# Update Parent Standard Object Getting Sum Value from Child in APEX

Tags: object, collections, salesforce, apex, soql

I am new in Apex. I want to write a trigger in apex for `before insert`. I have two standard objects (Contact, Opportunity).

```
SELECT  sum(amount),  Bussiness__c FROM opportunity
WHERE stagename='Closed Won' and id='006i000000Kt683AAB' GROUP BY   Bussiness__c
```

I want when trigger runs this get sum(Amount) field and Bussiness__c value and then update Contact Total_Business__c with Sum(Amount) Value. Here Bussiness__C is contact id at opportunity object.

Thanks in advance and Waiting for your positive Response.

Comment: Do you use currency management or are all values you see in the system in same currency specified at organisation's level?

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm assuming yo don't have currencies enabled in your org (if you'll see "CurrencyIsoCode" somewhere on your objects you'll have to modify this design a bit).
2. I am a lazy person and you didn't write anything about amount of data you expect. What I've written will work when there's reasonable amount of Opportunities per contact. If you'll start hitting the governor limit of 50K query rows it'd have to be done differently (I'll write a bit about it at the end).
3. I am not going to give you a ready solution because "homemade rollup summary" is one of assignments you might encounter during SF DEV 501 certification. I'll just outline some pointers and food for thought.

I wouldn't do it `before insert`, it's easier in `after insert, after update` (you didn't think about recalculation when the Amount changes, did you?). There should also be something said about `after delete, after undelete` if your users are allowed to delete Opportunities.

First thing is to build a set of "contacts we'll have to recalculate":

```
Set<Id> contactIds = new Set<Id>();
for(Opportunity o : trigger.old){
    contactIds.add(o.Business__c);
}
for(Opportunity o : trigger.new){
    contactIds.add(o.Business__c);
}
contactIds.remove(null);
```

This forces recalculation for all related contacts and ignores opportunities without contact. It'll fire always... which is not the best thing because on insert, delete, undelete you'd want it to fire always but on update you'd want it to fire only when Amount or Contact changes (trigger.old will hold different contact than trigger.new). You can control these scenarios by using stuff like `Trigger.isUpdate`, read up about it.

Anyway - you got an unique set of Contact Ids. I've said I'd do it in "after" trigger because at that point the new Amount is already saved to database and you can query it back from it:

```
SELECT Business__c, SUM(Amount) sumAmount
FROM Opportunity
WHERE Business__c IN :contactIds
```

This type of queries returns an "AggregateResult" that you'll have to parse like that:

```
List<Contact> contactsToUpdate = new List<Contact>();
for(AggregateResult ar : [SELECT Business__c, SUM(Amount) sumAmount
    FROM Opportunity
    WHERE Business__c IN :contactIds]){

    System.debug(ar);
    contactsToUpdate.add(new Contact(Id = (Id) ar.get('Business__c'),
        Total_Business__c = (Double) ar.get('sumAmount)
    );
}
update contactsToUpdate;
```

As I said - it's a basic outline, should get you started.

---

This thing queries all opportunities for given contact. Your trigger can fire on at most 200 Opps. Imagine a situation where you change contact on all 200 opps -> gives you 400 contacts you need to update to clear/fix old value and to set new value. With 50K rows limit, assuming no other business logic is triggered (like update of Accounts? Action that started because some Opportunity Products were added?) it gives you problems when on average 1 contact is involved in 125 Opps. It sounds like a ridiculous problem but there are scenarios when you need to do it differently.

In such cases you can attack it from another angle. You don't really need to query all opps for given Contact, it's lazy. You couuld instead learn the current value of total business (put 0 if it happens to be null) and then add/substract all changes to the amount as needed, looking only at your trigger.old and trigger.new. It makes for more code and more planning upfront but the performance will increase significantly and this solution will scale as the amount of opps grow (it'll continue to look at only the current max of 200 opps in the trigger's scope).

Another approach would be to accept some delay in this rollup summary and write a batch job for it.